# Trouble with Outlook 2007 searching

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

The problem I am having is a user is not able to search their own inbox. Every other employee is not having this problem but employee A. If Employee A connects to Employee B's inbox they can search normally without any problems. If Employee B connects to Employee A's mailbox they can also search normally. Employee B can also search employee B's inbox normally. Why is it employee A can not search their own emails. The search function does not return anything not even "no results found" its almost like it is disabled.

Things we tried:

- restarting exchange server
- Moving the inbox
- changing storage groups
- repaired index
- disabled search from control panel and rebuilt it
- rebuilt outlook profile
- rebuilt active directory profile

Thanks in advance this has been really bugging us.

Comment: Try [these](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2769651/outlook-search-returns-no-matches-found) options.

Comment: Ended up solving the problem. We had to delete the user account on active directory and destroy the connection between the exchange server. We then re created the account and copied over all the emails. The search works now. Pretty much re created the account from the ground up as a brand new user.